# How does Berlin Transport Validation Stamp mark current date and/or expiry date?

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, berlin

Below is an image of my seven day unlimited travel ticket for Berlin B Section:

[image]

I have painted black on its printed serial number, and have circled the validation stamp impression in red.

I bought it on 11th Nov about 11am, from a ticket vending machine in Wedding S Station, for 30 Euros, and immediately validation stamped it to start using it. Now, I can calculate 7 days from 11th, inclusive, are till 17th, inclusive.

My question is where in validation stamp its mentioned that it was stamped on 11th Nov? What can I say to Ticket Inspector on 16th or 17th if he says its expired. (At Gesundbrunnen Metro Station the lady at info desk said its expired today, when I asked her same question, although we both struggled in German and English language. When I said I bought today, she said ok.)

So, could you please interpret the validation stamp, part by part, and/or ticket (or any other part), to prove that it is valid for 7 days.

Edit: One more sample of validation stamp I got, on different ticket, one time use, Eur 2.70, Date 10th Nov, Time somewhere 11:30ish AM, Berlin Airport TXL

[image]

Edit2: Ok,

1. `Do` means *Donnerstag*, Thursday. `Fr` means *Freitag*, Friday.
2. 11:40 is time in first ticket, 11:00 in second.
3. Looks like `45` is the week number of year 2016, from Nov 7 to 13.
4. What does `6` mean (rotated 90°, after 45)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After the time-of-day on the stamp is a day-of-week in letters and a week number in numbers.

The 7-day ticket is stamped on **Fr**iday of week **45** in 201**6**.

The single ticket from Tegel is stamped on Thursday (in German: **Do**nnerstag) of week **45** in 201**6**.

The stamp shows the date and time you *validated* the ticket, which is when the validity *begins*. The machines are not smart enough to know which kind of ticket you validate, but will put the same stamp on any piece of paper you stick into them.

If you hold on to your ticket for 10 years and they don't change the design in the meantime, you could ride on it once again ....

Comment: The bottommost line of the serial number area has 161111, which in my view is the date sold. So I doubt they would accept it in 10 years time, even if the design does not change.

Comment: @Willeke: It's a bit academic, since (a) ticket inspectors probably won't routinely check _that_ small print of every ticket they're presented with, (b) the number of people who would even try that is too small to worry about anyway, and (c) even if the ticket technology doesn't change in the next 10 years, the effort and care needed to preserve the paper ticket in a reasonably pristine and readable state would not be worth saving the price of a ticket ...

Comment: Thanks, accepting this answer, as it answered all questions :) 6 means 2016.. Now I can point it to if somebody asks me, as the lady at info counter on Gesundbrehann said, oh this is expiry date and I was like what?

Comment: Since the ticket is most likely some thermopaper, it will have completely faded within ten years. But yeah, nice academic exercise ;)

Comment: There will certainly be changes in price to the ticket by then.

Comment: Tickets are invalid anyway long before 10 years have gone due to price changes. After each price change, there is usually only a short grace period, in which you can use tickets bought for the old price.

Comment: Actually, a good inspector would accept the ticked only if the year ends with a 6, _and 11/11 is a Thursday_. This will happen again in  2146, 2196, 2236, 2366, 2416... And assuming an inflation of 1.5%, the price will be 209€ in 2146...

Comment: @sweber: The Thursday of week 45 is a Thursday in every year. It is not always the 11th of November, but the validation stamp does not say the 11th of anything -- that is an _inference_, not in the content of the stamp.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Arrg, you are right...

Answer (score 4):

Note: I am adding my own observations as an answer, but would love to get a definitive explanation to the validation stamp contents.

As mentioned in my own edits,

1. Do and Fr means days of the week,
2. 45 is the week number (7th to 13th Nov)
3. 11:40 is time
4. Duration is printed just below stamp, 7-tag in first image, Ein....something in second, so 7 days and One (Journey?)

As detailed un below screenshot taken from [BVG's website](https://shop.bvg.de/index.php/product/239/show/0/0/0/0/buy), week long ticket with end on 7th day Midnight.

[image]

Text of above Screenshot:

> 7-Day-Ticket
>
> Travel as often as you want for seven consecutive calendar days.
>
> The 7-Day-Ticket is valid for seven consecutive calendar days. Validity begins on the first day of the validity period printed on the ticket or from the time of validation and ends on the seventh calendar day, at midnight. For example, from validation at 9.30 a.m. on a Tuesday until midnight on the following Monday.
>
> The Ticket is transferable and can also be used from other persons.

Comment: @Willeke Done, although was in mobile :)